# ms sql row_number() function - won't let me use within the same statement

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a the following sql statement:

```
$sql = "select siteid, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY siteid) as rownum FROM nwsite WHERE rownum >= 4";
```

"rownum" works when i use the name outside of the query (e.g. in a foreach loop) but when it comes to using it as a WHERE clause it never works.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: My understanding is that analytic functions are a post processing step: once the result set is determined, the set can be fed to the analytic function to determine things such as row number, what row is before, what row follows, etc. So the analytic can't be in the WHERE clause since it isn't applied until after the where clause is computed. Hence wrapping in subquery seems to be the generally the way to to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the where clause is evaluated before the window function row_number is computed, you can't include that column in your where clause.

You can structure the query like this:

select siteid, rownum from (select siteid, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY siteid) as rownum FROM nwsite) nw WHERE rownum >= 4

In this case the inner query is computed in its entirety and then passed to the outer query where the rownum column can be acted upon.

Comment: Wouldn't a `having` clause work as well, without having to do a subselect?

Comment: @MarcB No, you can't use a HAVING clause because ms sql sucks. It's perfectly fine in Mysql.

Comment: @JasonFuller - The `ROW_NUMBER` runs after the `HAVING` so it doesn't make any more sense to allow it to be referenced there either. MySQL hasn't got around to implementing window functions at all yet. If and when they do their lack of adherence to the SQL Standard on this issue will bite them.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to

- wrap your select statement into a subselect
- use the `rownum` alias in the outer query

**SQL Statement**

```
select *
from   (
         select siteid
                , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY siteid) as rownum 
         FROM   nwsite 
       ) q
where  rownum >= 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
$sql = "select siteid, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY siteid) as rownum FROM nwsite WHERE row_number() >= 4";
```

You can't use the alias defined in the columns part on the same WHERE clause. The WHERE clause doesn't have that information yet.

Answer (score 1):

Use common table expression :

```
with Result (field1, field2...,rn)
as
(select field1, field2..., rn=row_number() over (partition by field1 order by field 2)
from yourTable)
select * from result where rn<=3 ; -- top 3 in each group
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also define the `RowNum` in a `CROSS APPLY`, which will allow you to reference it.

```
select siteid, 
       RowNum
FROM nwsite 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY siteid)) CxA(rownum)
WHERE rownum >= 4
```

Comment: [This does not work correctly here](http://sqlmag.com/blog/tip-apply-and-reuse-column-aliases)

Comment: Here's an [archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160329191224/http://sqlmag.com/blog/tip-apply-and-reuse-column-aliases) to @MartinSmith 's link above.  See also for a similar explanation of why it doesn't work: https://blog.philipsymons.com/2015/03/28/cross-apply-with-ranking-and-analytical-functions/